# Issue when binding C functions Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, raspberry-pi-zero

I am trying to control a laser pointer with my raspberry Pi.
To do so, I bought 2 servos with a PTZ board and attached the laser to the servos.
The servos and PTZ board came with some code written in C to control them (the full code can be found here: https://github.com/arducam/pca9685)

The rest of my code (that goes along with the servo control) is written in Python (by me), so I am trying to get the C functions provided with the PTZ board to work with my Python code.

If I run this code in C:

```c
#define I2C_ADDR  0x80       //i2c address
#define SERVO_UP_CH  0       //The upper servo Channel
#define SERVO_DOWN_CH  1     //The under servo Channel
uint8_t ServoUpDegree = 90;
uint8_t ServoDownDegree = 90;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    PCA9685_init(I2C_ADDR);
    PCA9685_setPWMFreq(60);  // Analog servos run at ~60 Hz updates
    setServoDegree(SERVO_UP_CH, ServoUpDegree);
    setServoDegree(SERVO_DOWN_CH, ServoDownDegree);
}
```

Then both my servos get set to 90 degree and everything works as intended. The function `PCA9685_init`, `PCA9685_setPWMFreq` and `setServoDegree` are from the code provided with the PTZ board.

However when I run the following code in Python, nothing happens (my servos do not move).

```py
from ctypes import *
import os

servofile = "/home/pi/mu_code/PCA9685_servo_driver.so"
servodriver=CDLL(servofile, mode = os.RTLD_LAZY)

ServoDownDegree = 90
ServoUpDegree = 90
SERVO_UP_CH = 0
SERVO_DOWN_CH =1
I2C_ADDR = 0x80

servodriver.PCA9685_init(I2C_ADDR)
servodriver.PCA9685_setPWMFreq(60)

print("so far so good.")

servodriver.setServoDegree(SERVO_UP_CH, ServoUpDegree)
servodriver.setServoDegree(SERVO_DOWN_CH, ServoDownDegree)

print("still good.")
```

Both my lines get printed and my IDE does not have any problem running the code, so I do not understand why my servos do not move.

I created a test function in C that just print out "Hello word" when called:

```c
void PrintHello(int n) 
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0;i<=n; i++)
    {
        printf("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

and when in my Python code I write `servodriver.PrintHello(3)` I get the proper output in Python.
So it looks like my problem is not necessarily between my C functions and my Python code.

Any idea what could be the issue? I would like to be able to use the provided C functions because I seriously doubt I have the required knowledge to translate them from C to Python.

Comment: You didn't set argtypes and restype.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica You are correct, setting argtypes and restype solved my issue! Thank you very much for the swift answer.